# What is the property of the persistence.xml file to add custom entity listener?

Tags: jpa-2.0, eclipselink

I can't manage to find the property of the persistence.xml file with Eclipselink to add a default entity listener. Only example for the orm.xml file.

Does this property exist in the persistence unit configuration file?

Answer (score 3):

There is no such a property in persistence.xml. With EclipseLink and other JPA implementation they are defined in orm.xml (or in other file referenced by `mapping-file` element persistence.xml) as follows:

```
<persistence-unit-metadata>
  <persistence-unit-defaults>
    <entity-listeners>
      <entity-listener class="somepackage.YourListener">
        <pre-persist method-name="method1"/>
        <post-persist method-name="method2"/>
        <pre-remove method-name="method3"/>
        <post-remove method-name="method4"/>
        <pre-update method-name="method5"/>
        <post-update method-name="method6"/>
        <post-load method-name="method7"/>
      </entity-listener>
      <entity-listener class="other">
        <pre-persist method-name="someMethod"/>            
      </entity-listener>
    </entity-listeners>
  </persistence-unit-defaults>
</persistence-unit-metadata>
```